# Don't found the class BeaconService

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a beacon ranger, but the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.d(TAG, "debug");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);

    edit.setText("working");

    beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, List<Beacon> beacons) {
            edit.setText("Ranged beacons: " + beacons);
        }
    });
}
```

Gives me an exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.estimote.sdk.service.BeaconService$InternalLeScanCallback
```

What should I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try to set your android:minSdkVersion to 18